# Enabling gzip compression for CSS and JS files with Django compressor on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-compressor

I am currently working on a small Django project that is deployed on Heroku. In order to optimize the website's performance, I decided to use the django-compressor package to merge and minify all the JavaScript and CSS files. I am using the offline compression option, as it is the only one that works on Heroku.

However, I have noticed that the compressed CSS and JS files are not being gzipped when delivered to the client. This is causing the benefits I gained from using the compressor to be lost. I have been trying to find a solution to this issue, but I have not been able to find an easy way to turn on gzip for the compressor when using offline compression.

I would like to avoid a complex setup with S3, as this is a small site and I am looking for a simple solution that can be easily implemented on Heroku.

My question is:
Is there an easy way to turn on gzip for compressor when using offline compression? And how can I implement it on Heroku?

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.